# sql alchemy query get stucked depending on value

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm fairly new to python and MySql too. I'm trying to import data received in excel files into MySql using python. The scripts runs quiet ok, but I've a simple select part, which does not work properly.
It tries to retrieve data from a single table storing the already imported file names, categorized by file types. So the table has these two columns and few hundred lines.

```
CREATE TABLE `imp_doc` (
  `docname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `doc_type` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`docname`),
  KEY `doctype` (`doc_type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The script runs with all "file types", except one. When that one is sent as value to the select, the script stalls without error message.

The script with the "doc_type" parameter set to "ibot" which makes it to stall!

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.pool import NullPool

engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://userid:password@0.0.0.0:3306/mydb', poolclass = NullPool)
engine.echo = True
conn = engine.connect()

saved_list =[]
doc_type="ibot"
query = "SELECT docname FROM imp_doc WHERE doc_type = %s"
cur=conn.execute(query, (doc_type,))
for (docname) in cur:
    dn=docname[0]
    dn=unicode.encode(dn,'cp1252')
    saved_list.append(str(dn))
print saved_list
cur.close()
```

The result, it seems python is waiting for result from MySql, but in the db the connection is in "sleep".

```
2016-12-28 14:18:15,407 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode'
2016-12-28 14:18:15,407 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2016-12-28 14:18:15,598 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT DATABASE()
2016-12-28 14:18:15,598 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2016-12-28 14:18:15,987 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test plain returns' AS CHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2016-12-28 14:18:15,997 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2016-12-28 14:18:16,187 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test unicode returns' AS CHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2016-12-28 14:18:16,187 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2016-12-28 14:18:16,747 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT docname FROM imp_doc WHERE doc_type = %s
2016-12-28 14:18:16,757 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('ibot',)
```

When I run the same code with other doc_type value it works perfectly:

```
2016-12-28 14:31:45,105 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode'
2016-12-28 14:31:45,105 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2016-12-28 14:31:45,306 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT DATABASE()
2016-12-28 14:31:45,306 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2016-12-28 14:31:45,727 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test plain returns' AS CHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2016-12-28 14:31:45,727 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2016-12-28 14:31:45,947 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test unicode returns' AS CHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2016-12-28 14:31:45,957 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2016-12-28 14:31:46,507 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT docname FROM imp_doc WHERE doc_type = %s
2016-12-28 14:31:46,507 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('wiz',)
['WIZARD_2015-W1001-20160102.xlsx', 'WIZARD_2016-W0104-20160612.xlsx', 'WIZARD_2016-W16.xlsx', 'WIZARD_2016-W17.xlsx', 'WIZARD_2016-W18.xlsx', 'WIZARD_2016-W19.xlsx', 'WIZARD_2016-W20.xlsx', 'WIZARD_2016-W21.xlsx', 'WIZARD_2016-W22.xlsx', 'WIZARD_2016-W23.xlsx', 'WIZARD_2016-W24.xlsx', 'WIZARD_2016-W25.xlsx', 'WIZARD_2016-W26.xlsx', 'WIZARD_2016-W27.xlsx', 'WIZARD_2016-W28.xlsx', 'WIZARD_2016-W29.xlsx', 'WIZARD_2016-W30.xlsx', 'WIZARD_2016-W31.xlsx', 'WIZARD_2016-W32.xlsx', 'WIZARD_2016-W33.xlsx', 'WIZARD_2016-W34.xlsx', 'WIZARD_2016-W35.xlsx', 'WIZARD_2016-W36.xlsx', 'WIZARD_2016-W37.xlsx', 'WIZARD_2016-W38.xlsx', 'WIZARD_2016-W39.xlsx', 'WIZARD_2016-W40.xlsx', 'WIZARD_2016-W41.xlsx', 'WIZARD_2016-W42.xlsx', 'WIZARD_2016-W43.xlsx', 'WIZARD_2016-W44.xlsx', 'WIZARD_2016-W45.xlsx', 'WIZARD_2016-W46.xlsx', 'WIZARD_2016-W47.xlsx', 'WIZARD_2016-W48.xlsx', 'WIZARD_2016-W49.xlsx', 'WIZARD_2016-W50.xlsx']
```

Running the select in MySql works of course too:

```
docname                                 doc_type    
Hotspot Detail 2.0 iBot_20161226.xlsx   ibot
Hotspot Detail 2.0 iBot_20161225.xlsx   ibot
Hotspot Detail 2.0 iBot_20161224.xlsx   ibot
20161226 def.xlsx                       def
20161225 def.xlsx                       def
20161224 def.xlsx                       def
20161223 def.xlsx                       def
```

I'm sure the issue is not the value of the parameter, but please give me some help to understand why the same select works sometimes and does not work in other cases.
Thanks

Comment: One further comment. It seems the problem occurs when the result values contain space in the docname! Running the script with

Comment: this modification works, but of course does not provide the required result:  query = "SELECT replace(docname,' ','_') FROM imp_doc WHERE doc_type = %s"

Comment: The replace function did not solve entirely the problem. In fact if I replace the spaces with different characters than "_", I get different behaviour!!! This seems very scary and makes the whole code unreliable. Even using ORM istead of textual SQL gives similar behaviour. The issue seems to be connected to the "mysqlconnector". Replacing that with "pymysql" seems provided a workaround, but the original issue remains.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the SQLAlchemy [text()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#using-textual-sql) function with your code?

E.g. something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import text

query = text("SELECT docname FROM imp_doc WHERE doc_type = :type")
cur=conn.execute(query, type=doc_type)
```

Technically what you've got looks valid, but using `text()` is a SQLAlchemy best practice for writing textual SQL and sometimes you get unexpected behavior if you don't use it (in my experience).

Comment: Thanks PJ taking the time to answare my question. I adapted my code as you suggested, but still the code get stucked. Anyhow I will use this syntax from now on for textual SQL. Applying on the modified code the replace function as commented above makes this version of the query work too. Any idea why?